# TimeZone.getDefault() doesn't give me time zone where I am

Tags: android

This hardcoded `GMT+2` works like a charm.

```
calendarCurrent.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+2"));
```

Of cource I don't need it hardcoded, so I'm using

```
calendarCurrent.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

But this never give me proper value. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just ran `Log.d(TAG, TimeZone.getDefault().toString());` on a phone set to UK time and got `org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["GMT",mRawOffset=0,mUseDst=true]`. (We're not in DST now but I think that mUseDst might mean it knows about DST in the future.) What does yours say?

Comment: what are expected/actual values, and what is the timezone set in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

I was guess it should work automatically.

But I saw people using **setDefault(..)**

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

Answer (score -1):

The default timezone will be automatically detected by the system, so you don't need to call TimeZone.setDefault() explicitly.

Timezone auto detection does not work on the emulator, but you can use the -timezone launch flag to set it.

Also, the recommended way to change timezone is through Settings app, which not not included in the current sdk ..
For now you can use the following:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

It works with

`<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>`

Comment: ...i'd care to know why the down-vote on this answer.  It's complete, informative, and helped me understand why I wasn't getting a correct TimeZone when testing on an emulator.